# jQuery Ajax - scripts are contained, even if page is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using jQuery ajax to render an HTML page which also contains javascript functions.
my code is:

```
function ChartBook() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Charts/ChartBook',
            dataType: 'html',
            id: 1,
            traditional: true,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (content) {
                $(document.body).empty();
                $(document.body).html(content);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('An unexpected error occured.');
            }
        });            
    }
```

The page Chartbook contains a function "GetChartData()".

It runs fine, but when I call another page in same manner, The Chartbook page is now not in the body, but I can still get alert message from function "GetChartData".

How can scripts be still there, while I have removed the page from html body with $(document.body).empty()?

**EDIT:**

Another problem is that, if I recall the "Chartbook" page and return to the previous page, The alert message comes twice from the function "GetChartData()". the number of alert message increases each time I load Chartbook page and return to previous page.

Comment: When javascript is loaded, it's loaded. Removing the code or reference to the js file does not remove the loaded scripts.

Comment: My question is that, are scripts still there, even their page is removed from master page body? How can I remove these scripts too.

Comment: I'm finding this Question confusing! :D So this Ajax'ed ChartBook page contains self-executing JavaScript which invokes `GetChartData()`? Which this self-executing code which is not _appended_ but instead _replaces_ the current `$('body')` page html? I'm sure the `.error()` is pretty much only invoked if the ajax retrieves an HTTP 404 or 500 error of some kind

Comment: @Zorro i guess they will be gone if you load another page that doesnt include those js scripts

Comment: @MackieeE i guess the best way is to look at the developer tools when the js is loaded to see the data being passed, this can be done by looking inside (if you are using chrome)chrome's developer tools->network tab

Comment: for me the best way to debug js is through the js console.. because you can trigger js functions from the console

Comment: @Zorro - and the answer is, yes the scripts are still in memory, as removing the markup does not remove the javascript that has been loaded into memory. The only way to remove such javascript would be to overwrite the function with a new function with the same name that does nothing, you can not remove javascript from memory once it's loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The scripts are usually placed on top of the `body` in a `header` section. Therefore *they will not be removed* by `$(document.body).empty();` which you could also write as `$('body').empty();`.

Comment: How I can remove these scripts too? Their page is no more in the HTML DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter if you remove all html they are still in DOM check [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml)